# Convert decimal entity and hexadecimal entity to HTML named entity

Tags: java, character, special-characters

As my question suggests, is there a way or some libraries in java that converts decimal or hexadecimal entity to html named entity.

For example,

Input: &#945 or &#x03B1

Output: &alpha

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/escape-html-encode-string/

Comment: input wont have actual symbol, it will have hexadecimal or decimal entity. Also I have tried using StringUtils... For &#945, its returning &amp;#945 which I don't want